# Djangoでモデルのカスタムカラムに名前を付けたい

Tags: python, sqlite, django

Djangoでモデルを作るとき、

```
class UserCustom(models.Model):
    hoge = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, help_text='hogeを入力して下さい', verbose_name=u'別名')
```

のようにすれば、別名をつけることが出来ます。

```
class UserCustom(models.Model):
    hoge = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, help_text='hogeを入力して下さい', verbose_name=u'別名')
    def custom_column(self):
        return 'bar'
```

のようにcustom_columnを追加した時に、
custom_columnに別名を付けたいです。
※このテクニックをカスタムカラムというのかわかりませんが、便宜上こう名づけました。

情報が無いため試しにこれらを行ってみましたが、

```
def custom_column(self):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'カスタムカラム'
```

や

```
def custom_column(self):
    self.verbose_name = u'カスタムカラム'
```

ダメでした。
よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: ここで`custom_column`というメッソドを作っているようですが、たぶん、djangoのモデルFieldとして認識されないだろうかと思います。custom_columnを追加目的はなんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`admin.py`の`admin.ModelAdmin`で定義するようです:

```
class UserCustomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (..., 'custom_column',)

    def custom_column(self):
        return 'bar'
```

参照
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2156277/24718

Comment: 伝わり割りにくくてすみませんが、
普通のカラムを追加したいのではなく、
DBのテーブル自体にはカラムを追加せずに、
メソッド的なものを追加してadminなどで表示させるために、あたかもカラムに見せかけたいと思っています。

    def custom_column(self):
        return 'bar'

Comment: この`custom_column`は、データを持っていないでしょうか？それとも、現状の`hoge`の代わりに表示したいでしょうか？

Comment: データを持たずに、adminで表示するために使います。
hogeは別名の例のために記載したもので、custom_columnに影響しません。

Comment: ‘admin.ModelAdmin‘で定義するといくでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

`メソッド名.short_description`を定義すれば、管理サイトのカラムのタイトルが変更できます。

models.py

```
class UserCustom(models.Model):
    ...
    def custom_column(self):
        return 'bar'
    custom_column.short_description = u'カスタムカラム'
```

admin.py

```
list_display = ('custom_column', ... )
```

参考URL: [Django admin サイト](http://django-docs-ja.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)